# Getting Error While force close/relaunch from eclipse

Tags: android

I am stuck with an issue and not getting any of solution. when i launch my app from eclipse first time it is running proper but when i do it again then it gives me an error message in logcat and my device get dim dim dim and work very slow
Error:

```
02-13 15:37:56.519: ERROR/IMGSRV(2495): PVRSRVEventObjectWait  Timeout!
02-13 15:37:57.519: ERROR/ShutdownThread(2495): IsShutDownStarted()
```

After Restarting the phone it work fine for first time. I am using Samsung Galaxy Tab.